# How to do case sensitive queries on dynamic fields

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I want to do case sensitive queries against dynamic fields in a RavenDB index. I have seen that this can be done using an AbstractAnalyzerGenerator thing, but I have not found information on how to use it.

My document class looks similar to:

```
class Thing {
   public string Name;
   public DateTime CreatedAt;
   public Dictionary<string, object> Properties;
}
```

The index map is set up like this:

```
Map = things => from thing in things
select new { Name = thing.Name,
             CreatedAt = thing.CreatedAt,
             _ = thing.Properties.Select( p => 
                     p.CreateField(p.Key, p.Value, false, true) );
}
```

Now I would like to use this magic AbstractAnalzyzerGenerator thing to make some of the property fields case sensitive, based on their name. Unfortunately I don't know how.. :)

Answer (score 0):

ErikR,
If you need case sensitive, you need to do it like this:

```
                 p.CreateField(p.Key, p.Value, false, **false**) );
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I do this no documents are returned. It is quite ironic, because the studio even suggests the same value that I tried without success, when I enter some junk instead for the proper value. But, no documents for me. If I query only for a "fixed" field, I get the documents I expect, but I can't seem to narrow the query using the dynamic fields when the are not analyzed (as in **false** above?).

Comment: I guess I should try to put together something that fails to illustrate, but I will have to get back regarding that.